# SQL Server: Create rows of a dynamic range using a select statement

Tags: sql-server, select

Using Ruby you can produce an array with the following code:

```
some_range = (1..10).to_a
# Returns => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I'm looking for something similar in SQL Server using a SELECT statement. i.e. I would like to produce this table:

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
etc
```

With a statement that looks something like this:

```
DECLARE @ids TVP
INSERT @ids
    (id)
SELECT RANGE(0..10000)
```

My use case is that I want a quick way of testing SPs that takes @ids as a TVP. Does SQL Server provide something that achieves this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a recursive CTE like this if I want to generate a numbers table:

```
;WITH NumberGen AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Number
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Number + 1 AS Number
    FROM NumberGen
    WHERE Number < $#RowsToBeGenerated$
)
INSERT INTO $Table$($Field$)
    (   
        SELECT Number
        FROM NumberGen
        WHERE Number BETWEEN 1 AND $#RowsToBeGenerated$
    )
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any reason that you use $variable$ instead of <variable>, for sql queries in terms of conventions?

Comment: No no, I only use the $ sign in my snippets as a placeholder for actual values. They have no real meaning.

Comment: I hit the recursion stack limit when trying to generate more than 100 rows. ("The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion"). Do you know a way around this? I was hoping to generate 100k + rows

Comment: The `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);` should lift the recursion limit. Did you use it in your CTE?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Range INT = 10

    ;with cte
    as
    (
    select 1 as value
    union all
    select value + 1 from cte where value < @Range
    )
    select * from cte
```